# SSH Wrapper for Asynchronous connections

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, ssh

i am working on mac application development,need help regarding connecting to remote system asynchronously with parallel execution.

How i can create 5 parallel threads in COCOA programming(at run time need to create based on count i.e 10 threads may be),
Need to connect to 5 MAC machines at a time based on thread count.

Please Guide me with SSH Wrapper and parallel execution of thread in COCOA(Mac) programming.

Thanks,
Shabana